# Does Rundeck provide a plugin to load jobs from a file on boot?

Tags: rundeck

I'm aware that Rundeck has a SCM plugin that loads jobs from git, and there is also the `rd` command line tool that loads YAML files with an API call, but I don't want those.

Instead I want to tell rundeck, "look at /opt/rundeck/jobs.yml and use those jobs", if that file changes then update accordingly, even if I need to restart rundeck. Then I can render the jobs.yml file using a template with a config management tool like Ansible.

Does such a plugin exist?

I've searched on:

https://github.com/rundeck-plugins and
https://docs.rundeck.com/plugins/

But haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

One idea to experiment with is to create a local git repo, here is an example Ansible playbook that outlines the rough idea:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: initialize a repository
      command: git init /home/vagrant/jobs
      args:
        creates: /home/vagrant/jobs/.git/HEAD

    - name: render projects
      copy:
        dest: /home/vagrant/jobs/jobs.yml
        owner: vagrant
        group: vagrant
        mode: 0644
        content: |
          foo: 42
          bar: 42
          baz: 42
          bat: 42
      register: jobs

    - name: add new jobs to git repo
      command: git add jobs.yml
      args:
        chdir: /home/vagrant/jobs
      when: jobs is changed

    - name: commit changes
      command: git commit -m 'Add jobs'
      args:
        chdir: /home/vagrant/jobs
      when: jobs is changed
```